# HTML5 Video is very slow to load on Android Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I'm using html5 video and everything is working well on desktop and ios safari and chrome. However Chrome on Android is incredibly slow to load, however it does play eventually. I tried the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688845/html5-video-very-slow-loading) but the video index is in the right place. Does anyone know what else could be causing the problem?

Here's my code:

```
<video class="video" width="100%" height="auto" controls>
    <source src="{{ mp4.url }}" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="{{ webm.url }}" type="video/webm">
    <source src="{{ ogv.url }}" type="video/ogv">
</video>
```

Comment: have a look at overall encoding, not just the moov atom... eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270365/confused-about-streaming-video-in-html5/28270734#28270734

Comment: OK thanks @Offbeatmammal I'll try look into my encoding. I was using http://www.online-convert.com/ to get the right file types. Maybe their encoding is a bit funny?